# Translating Confusing Conditional Shorthand

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, shorthand

Here's the statement:

```
var H = dr ? ((C < 0 ? 0 : 1) - C) / dr : 0
```

dr and C are floats.

I don't know what "dr ?" means because it's just a float and not a true/false value.

I was wondering if someone could translate this to a traditional if-else statement thing. The "/ dr : 0" thing is confusing me too.

Comment: 0 is  falsey value

Comment: `dr ?` will check if your float is equal to `0.0` or not.

Comment: @Zenoo: Or `NaN`.

Answer (score 3):

[Leo Li's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49984160/157247) provides a translation, but your question seems more about using `dr` as a boolean when it's a "float":

> I don't know what "dr ?" means because it's just a float and not a true/false value.

There's no need for it to be. JavaScript coerces values. If `dr` really is a number, `dr ? x : y` will evaluate to `x` if `dr` is not `0` and not `NaN`, `y` if `dr` is `0` or `NaN`.

More generally: Any time a value is used in a condition (whether it's the conditional operator as in your question, or `if (value)`, or `while (value)`, etc.), any *falsy* value coerces to `false` and any *truthy* value coerces to `true`. The falsy values are `0`, `NaN`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`; all other values are truthy.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an equivalent form:

```
var H;

if (dr) {
  if (C < 0) {
    H = (0 - C) / dr
  } else {
    H = (1 - C) / dr
  }
} else {
  H = 0
}
```

Some explanations:

1. A conditional statement only look at if the statement (i.e. `(dr)` in this case) is a truthy value.  Every object in JavaScript can be evaluated as `true` or `false`. It is not necessary to be a boolean type.
2. `null` (Object), `undefined` (Undefined), `NaN` (Number), `false` (Boolean), `''` (String), and `+0/-0` (Number) are evaluated as `false` in JavaScript.
3. Since `dr` is a float (i.e. a `Number`, there is no `float` primitive types), it is truthy unless it is `0` or `NaN`.
4. As the question upon the ternary expression. People may consider a pseudo code:

`(conditional_statement)
  ? (truthy_condiction)
  : (falsey_condiction);`

By wrapped it with `()`, i.e. `var H = dr ? (((C < 0 ? 0 : 1) - C) / dr) : 0`, or just separate it by lines, as I did in the above, would make it easier to be understood.

Comment: @zenoo `I was wondering if someone could translate this to a traditional if-else statement thing.` thats exactly what this answer does?!

Comment: @JonasW. My bad.

Comment: I would just have declared `var H;` before everything else, then set `H = ...` in each `if` statement, otherwise this looks good.

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks for pointing out... I'm so used to `const` haha

Comment: *"and empty value in an Array are evaluated as false in JavaScript"* **No**, that is not true. No array, regardless of contents, is falsy. *"Since dr is a ...Number...it is truthy unless it is 0"* Or `NaN`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, You are correct, but not precise.  What I was saying is the member (or element) in an Array, not Array itself.  Array only record a reference thus always truthy.  If you try `const x = [,,,]` and `console.log(typeof x[0])` you will see `undefined` so it is falsey.  The reason why I added it is because some built-in function treat empty element differently, and it is worth mentioning.  But since there is a confusion, so I removed that statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are many falsy values in Javascript which are equivalent to false when evaluated in a conditional expression:
[Falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

If `dr` is 0, or any other falsy value, `H` will be 0, otherwise, it will evaluate to the value of the expression `((C < 0 ? 0 : 1) - C) / dr` which contains another ternary condition, which will be evaluated again in the same way